# Oracle Database Connection Error Listener Refused the Connection

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-connection

I just installed Oracle 11g on my work dev computer which has Windows 7 64-bit and is on a network with a domain set up.  When I try to connect to the "XE" database/SID using SQL Developer I get the following errors list below.

Any ideas?

I've researched online and tried a number of the solutions suggested and cannot get it to work.  I can confirm the following:

1. The database is started. I can connect using SQL Plus.
2. Both the OracleServiceXE and OracleXETNSListener services are started
3. Internet Information Systems (IIS) is installed and working properly.
4. In addition to not being able to connect with SQL Developer, when I the the "Get Started" web application, it doesn't work.

When I first tried to connect, the settings in SQL Developer were as follows:

```
Hostname: localhost
Port: 1521
SID: xe
```

However, I got the following error:

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12505
```

After researching I found that I should look at the listener end points (whatever that means) in the "listner.ora" file and confirm the hostname.  That file has the following:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
    (SID_LIST =
        (SID_DESC =
          (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
          (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Oracle\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
          (PROGRAM = extproc)
        )
        (SID_DESC =
          (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
          (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Oracle\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
          (PROGRAM = extproc)
        )
      )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = mycomputername.abc.de.mycompany.com.)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

When I saw that the host name was different I first tried changing "HOST" in the listener.ora file from "mycomputername.abc.de.mycompany.com." to "localhost"  and then to "127.0.0.1" (note the previous really has an extra period at the end).  After doing that, I still got the same error message.

Then, I put everything back the way it was in the "listener.ora" file and instead went to SQL Developer and changed my login information to the following:

```
Hostname: mycomputername.abc.de.mycompany.com.   (again... there really is a period at the end)
Port: 1521
SID: xe
```

I even tried it with just "mycomputername". Again, I got the error message:

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12505
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found help from a friend of a friend. Here's what he did.

First, note that he left the settings in the "listener.ora" file alone. Instead he did the following... all from the command prompt.

Step 1: Run SQL Plus directly from the command prompt as the "sysdba" to simulate SQL Plus within the command prompt.

```
C:\windows\system32>sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Step 2: Enter the following SQL Plus command to verify the database name (aka global name or SID). The return value was "XE".

```
SQL> select * from global_name;
```

Step 3: Enter the following SQL Plus command to set the listner to use the 'localhost' as the "HOST". Apparently, the listener this will override the settings in the "listner.ora" file. I think he said this is saved in the database somewhere and is not saved in a file.

```
SQL> alter system set LOCAL_LISTENER='(DESCRIPTION_LIST =  (DESCRIPTION = 
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521)) (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)
(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))))';
```

Step 4: Enter the following SQL Plus command to register what you set in step 3 above.

```
SQL> alter system register;
```

Step 5: Exit the SQL plus simulation in the command prompt.

```
SQL> exit
```

Comment: sounded like music to my ears, saved my life man, perfect